# ¿Como funciona el siguiente programa para elevar un número a una potencia?

Tags: java

Buen día comunidad, espero me puedan ayudar mi maestro me proporciono el siguiente programa para elevar un número a un potencia funciona correctamente pero no logro entender como es su funcionamiento muestro el código:

```
public class GFG {

    public static int power(int x, int y) {
        int temp;
        if (y == 0) {
            return 1;
        }
        temp = power(x, y / 2);

        if (y % 2 == 0) {
            return temp * temp;
        } else {
            if (y > 0) {
                return x * temp * temp;
            } else {
                return (temp * temp) / x;
            }
        }
    }

    // Driver code
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 2;
        int y = 3;
        System.out.println("Este es el resultado "+power(x, y));
    }
}
```

lo que principalmente me causa confusión es esta línea de código:

```
temp = power(x, y / 2);
```

no entiendo en este caso que valor es el que adopta temp espero me puedan explicar. Gracias.

Comment: Tienes toda la razon, lo que sucede es que mi profesor explica con un lenguaje bastante tecnico y en ocaciones me cuesta entenderlo por eso buscaba si aqui me podrian ayudar explicandome más sencillamente gracias

Comment: Esto es una funcion recursiva.. entendes que hace una funcion recursiva?

Comment: Si lo hehco por ejemplo entiendo que el primer if que se encuentra en el metodo power es para verificar que si la potencia es 0 entonces nos devolvera un 1 dado a que todo numero elevado a la potencia 0 es 1, el segundo if hace la operacion modulo con el valor que  y poseeque en este caso como el valor de y era tres pero se dividio entre dos queda como 1 entonces aplicando el modulo me da como resultado 1

Comment: @gbianchi una funcion recursiva es aquellas que se manda a llamar a si misma dentro de la funcion espero estar en lo correcto

Comment: perfecto.. entonces eso que decis que no entendes, es la funcion llamandose a si misma.. Para que se entienda, por mas que se llamen igual, y tengan el mismo codigo, es como llamar a otra funcion, cada vez que se llama a si misma... entonces solo tenes que seguir el codigo...

Comment: ok entonces entra al método hace la verificacion del primer if y si no se cumple se vuelve a llamar pero entonces que pasa con el código que viene despues de su llamado en que momento se procede a ejecutarlo?

Comment: cuando vuelve... es como llamar a otra funcion ;)